# Why am I not able to take the following string as input and add it to an ArrayList?

Tags: java

I was taking the address into an ArrayList but there's something wrong going on while taking the user input.

Ex: When I give the following input
"America"
"1, 2nd Street road"

Problem: The first string goes fine as it has no spaces and commas. But the second string is not getting added to the list. Only 1 is getting added.

I have tried using the next() and nextLine() but I wasn't able to add the whole string into the list as an object.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("Enter Location");
        list.add(sc.next());
        System.out.println("Enter the Address");
        list.add(sc.next());
        System.out.println(list);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using nextLine for both calls?

Comment: Space is the delimiter for scanner class. Basically, next() will take token as input which is separated by a delimiter.

Comment: @matt yes I did. But I didn't get it.

Comment: @Waterbyte can you please edit my code? I have tried it but I couldn't debug it.

Comment: I think it worked with nextLine for both places, but the list shows it as 3 items, because of the comma? https://ideone.com/3E9vqE

Comment: Yes, that's again a problem. @matt

Comment: It isn't actually 3 items. https://ideone.com/3E9vqE I have edited the paste, you can see it prints each entry on a new line.

Comment: @matt can you please check this https://ideone.com/G4kjiw

Comment: @SMR whenever you use a scanner.next, nextInt, nextDouble, etc. It doesn't consume the newline. So the first call to nextInt leaves the scanner with a newline character waiting to be read. Then you call nextLine and it gets an empty line. Add a nextLine() call after you ask for the number.

Comment: @matt Yes! I did exactly that and got it.

Answer (score 0):

according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace.

You will want to use a different delimiter pattern to fix your problem. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.util.regex.Pattern- for how to change the delimiter pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using `sc.next()` you should use `sc.nextLine()`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("Enter Location");
        list.add(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the Address");
        list.add(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println(list.size());
        for(String s: list)
            System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

Comment: The output shows three elements:
[America, 1, 2nd street road]

Comment: @SMR that is two elements, but one of them contains a comma. eg `America` and `1, 2nd street road`.

Comment: @SMR Its not 3 elements. You are confusing between the comma of your 2nd string and the comma of the print of array list.

Comment: @SMR I updated the print of `list`, check it out and see for yourself that you are getting only 2 lines and the size of `list`.

Comment: My bad. Yeah, I'll check it @OmriAttiya

Comment: @SMR that's a different question. Please follow the guide of [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Oops, I didn't know that. I'll not repeat that again @OmriAttiya

Comment: @SMR just ask it in as a new question

Comment: Yes, I tried doing the same but there was a 90 min window limit between two successive questions. @OmriAttiya